# stackoverflow error while serializing generic class in GSON

Tags: android, realm, realm-list

I am trying to build a generic object named request which can hold request related to different entities.

For example , Request can be created for fitness class , employee class or contact class. Now below is the code to check whether 
we have any offline data exists or not. `getNonSynced` function will return the `RealmResults` of data those are not synced.

i am adding that `realmResults` into the request class's `RealmList`. once request is created i am converting it into json string using GSON and this is the point where my app gets crashed and throwing `Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB`

**Function to get offline data and parse request**

```
  public <T extends  RealmModel > void checkOfflineData(){


    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

    Set<Class<? extends RealmModel>> realmObjectClasses = realm.getConfiguration().getRealmObjectClasses();

    for(Class modelClass: realmObjectClasses) {

            // fetch non synced data 

            RealmResults realmResults = getNotSynced(realm,modelClass);
            if(realmResults !=null && realmResults.size() > 0){

                //build a request 
                Request<T> request = new Request<T>();
                RealmList<T> realmList = new RealmList<T>();
                //add results to list
                realmList.addAll(realmResults.subList(0, realmResults.size()));
                request.setRequestList(realmList);

            }
    }

    // Parsing using GSON data


    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    builder.registerTypeAdapter(Request.class, new RequestSerializer());
    Gson gson = builder.create();
    String data = gson.toJson(request);



}
```

**Request Class**

```
public class Request<T>  {

private RealmList<T> requestList;

public RealmList<T> getRequestList() {
    return requestList;
}

public void setRequestList(RealmList<T> requestList) {
    this.requestList = requestList;
}
```

}

This is probably happening at the time of GSON tries to serialize `RealmList<T> requestList` where it might be trying to find the concrete type. All i am seeking is the way to box the class and provide appropriate class type to T

**Error**

```
    07-17 13:04:00.177 6076-6076/com.org.connectedhealth W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
        at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Native Method)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.writeField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:138)
07-17 13:04:00.178 6076-6076/com.org.connectedhealth W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:243)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:208)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:127)
07-17 13:04:00.179 6076-6076/com.org.connectedhealth W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:245)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:127)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:245)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
07-17 13:04:00.180 6076-6076/com.org.connectedhealth W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:127)
```

I have tried few things here, if i am explicitly providing a type specific object then gson does not throw error.

```
      Request<T> request = new Request<T>();
      RealmList<T> realmList = new RealmList<T>();

      // explicitly providing fitness object 
      realmList.add((T)new Fitness());
      request.setRequestList(realmList);
```

so i think i need to explore a way to return realm result that has specific type.

```
 private <T extends RealmModel> RealmResults<T> getNotSynced(Realm realm , Class<T> modelClass) {

        RealmResults<T>  realmResults =null;
        try{

            realmResults= realm.where(modelClass).equalTo("syncInfo.syncStatus", false).findAll();
        }catch (Exception e){

            Log.e(TAG ,"Exception "+e.getMessage());

        }

        return  realmResults;
    }
```

Comment: The problem is `T` not this code ...

Comment: yes but what i am seeking is possible solution

Comment: do not use circular references in T or mark such fields as not serializable

Comment: requestlist is required as that is the field that stores the request data of different type. i know it is a circular reference but again m seeking a solution over it and not using that field is not a solution form me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by replacing following line to convert realm result into realm list , it started working because `realmResults.subList(0, realmResults.size())` returns `List<T>` and `copyFromRealm` returns `List<RealmModel>`

From

```
realmList.addAll(realmResults.subList(0, realmResults.size()));
```

To

```
realmList.addAll(realm.copyFromRealm(realmResults));
```